# intellij usability question - how to add a button that opens working folder

Tags: intellij-idea, usability

There's a small feature I have been yearning about in intellij idea and I will give it a try in this forum, maybe it is already possible.

In brief: I want a button that opens the working folder of the project I am working on.

Since this is the folder I put my settings files I am doing the following operation  dozens of times a day -

open the run/debug configuration.
go to my activbe project tab.
copy the working directory.
open run (win+r).
paste the folder path and press enter.

X dozens of times.

Is there a way to add a button somewhere that opens my working folder?
BTW: I know that in the project settings - External tools - I can add actions. but there is no workingFolder in the macros. is there a way to add the working folder? (eventhough a button would be better)
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to manage files, why not do it right from IntelliJ? If you have to go to explorer, right click any file or folder in the project panel, and there's a "Show in Explorer" option in Windows (no default key mapping). There's also "Show Path" (ctrl+alt+F12), which lets you open Explorer to any parent directory of the selected file all the way up to the drive. Finally, "Copy Path" (ctrl+shift+C) will copy the absolute path to the clipboard. (This is in IDEA 10.5, but I know Copy Path has been there a long time.)

Comment: Those are really nice but i happen to create a lot of working folder during the day. The reason is that I have many servers and in order to debug I temporarily copy the content of a working folder to my computer and debug it localy (many firewalls and switches prevent me from debugging remotely, can only ftp files ). So after I set a temporary folder as working folder, I need a fast button to open it.

Comment: I guess I need a better definition of "working folder". I assumed that if you were in IntelliJ, any "working folder" you needed would be in your Project view somewhere.

Comment: Nope. Working directory is the directory that the jvm will use when searching for files. like double clicking it from that directory. it is defined in the run configurations.